# Creating a DTO for non-standard Json field

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

How can I create a Data Transformation Object class for what I believe to be a non-standard Json field?

Specifically I am looking at the [Rackspace Cloud Identity documentation](https://developer.rackspace.com/docs/cloud-identity/v2/developer-guide/) and there is this section:

```
"token":
  {
    "RAX-AUTH:authenticatedBy": [
        "PASSWORD"
            ],
    "expires": "2014-01-09T15:08:53.645-06:00",
    "id": "123abc5368901230076b12357897898"
  }
```

In creating my DTO Class entry I would have something like the following:

```
public class token
{
    public DateTime expires { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

How in the heck do I represent the Json data field RAX-AUTH:authenticatedBy so that the serialization handler can understand and map it correctly?

UPDATE:

My original question was for serializing the response but I realized my bigger problem is in the request DTO deserialization:

```
{
    "auth": {
        "RAX-AUTH:domain": {
            "name":"Rackspace"
        },
        "passwordCredentials": {
            "username":"<USERNAME>",
            "password":"<PASSWORD>"
        }
    }
}
```

I've tested the recommendations but the outbound Json has "domain" and not the "RAX-AUTH:domain" like the API is expecting:

```
[DataContract(Name="auth")]
public class CloudIdentityAuthRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("RAX-AUTH:domain")]
    public CloudIdentityDomain domain { get;  }

    [DataMember]
    public CloudIdentityPasswordCredentials passwordCredentials { get; }
}

[DataContract]
public class CloudIdentityDomain
{
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get { return "Rackspace"; } }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code where you are actually performing the serialization/sending the request. We have no idea what JSON serialization functionality you are using.

Comment: I am asking about building a DTO class that can be used with Json.NET...  The Rackspace API Auth request/response has this particular field 'RAX-AUTH:domain' and 'RAX-AUTH:authenticatedBy' which are the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that field is a string array. You can map that name to a property on your DTO using a [`DataMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[DataContract]
public class Token
{
    [DataMember(Name = "RAX-AUTH:authenticatedBy")]
    public string[] AuthenticatedBy { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "expires")]
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I tried naming the DataMember as you suggested without success.  Also, in case anyone else is trying your example, there is a slight correction:  [DataMember(Name="...")

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) (download it from NuGET) and you can do something like this

```
public class Token
{
    public DateTime expires { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("RAX-AUTH:authenticatedBy")]
    public IEnumerable<string> authenticatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize it like

```
var rackSpaceAuth = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(tokenjson);
```

Comment: That property isn't a string.

Comment: Please see my updated question, as the example you gave didn't seem to work for me...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that property will always be an array of strings, and depending on your serializer, you should be able to do this:

```
public class token
{
    public DateTime expires { get; set; }

    public string id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("RAX-AUTH:authenticatedBy")]
    public string[] authenticatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please see my updated question, as the example you gave didn't seem to work for me...